# Angular Quickstart Tutorial app.component.ts not showing in html

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

Can someone please explain why, when I run the Angular Quickstart Tutorial (from the official Angular 2 documentation) and it loads the html in `App.component.ts`, it does not load the component in the HTML directive?

Heres my code:

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>`,
})
export class AppComponent  { name = 'Angular'; }
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Angular QuickStart</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <base href="/">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

    <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>

    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>

    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('main.js').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <my-app>Loading AppComponent content heres ...</my-app>
  </body>
</html>
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

One last thing - it only allows me to edit the `.js` files for it to update in the browser, if I edit a `.ts` file.  In the `app.component.ts` file it won't show changes in the browser, but if I edit it in the `app.component.js` it does show the changes in the browser.

I am using Visual Studio to code.

Comment: ...you have two one last things, and neither of them is the last thing.

Comment: can you elaborate on your comment im new to angularjs2

Comment: That's nothing to do with Angular, or programming. I mean literally you have two different sentences starting with *"One last thing"*, neither of which is the final sentence of your post.

Comment: thanks i will post that on grammer flow next time lol but really am looking for Angular experts to jump in with some real help